# Interactions between asyncio, pytest, and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I have a Python 3.8 program which runs a coroutine that loops infinitely, scheduling other coroutines in the background via `create_task` but not awaiting them. These coroutines use SQLAlchemy's `AsyncEngine` to write some data to a database. If an exception is raised, the handler cancels the looping coroutine and then awaits the remaining background tasks via `gather`. This all seems to work fine.

Stripped-down example:

```
async def write_loop():
  async_engine: AsyncEngine = get_async_engine()
  while True:
    data = await get_some_data()
    bg_task: Task = asyncio.create_task(write_to_db(async_engine, data))
    outstanding_tasks.add(bg_task)
    bg_task.add_done_callback(outstanding_tasks.discard)

async def main():
  try:
    await write_loop()
  except:
    await asyncio.gather(*outstanding_tasks)
```

I'm using `pytest` and `pytest-asyncio` to implement some test cases exercising the above. The exception is forced via some patching, so the line with `gather` is the last thing that should happen. Each test case is decorated with `@pytest.mark.asyncio` to ensure that none share an event loop. They all pass when run individually. When running multiple at the same time, the SQLAlchemy writes would fail with `cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress`. Googling told me that I needed to turn off connection pooling in test, which seems to imply that the different tests are somehow sharing an `AsyncEngine` (or at least the underlying connection pool?) despite each creating its own.

Having done that, I no longer get the above error. However, now if I run too many tests at once, at least one times out (no matter how high I set the timeout). I can see that the point where it hangs is `await asyncio.gather(*outstanding_tasks)`. If I print the remaining tasks before calling `gather`, I see that they are in the `pending` state and have `wait_for=<_GatheringFuture pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object]>` (in addition to the callback that I attached).

I have the following questions:

- Why are the tests sharing anything in the way of the `AsyncEngine`? Does this have to do with the fact (I think) that they run in the same process?
- What does it mean that, when enough tests are run, the last few tasks never seem to get scheduled? My only guess was that they needed extra time, but I think I've disproven that with high timeouts.

In case it matters, the pytest functions are also parameterized such that each will be run multiple times with different arguments.

Edit: I should also mention that this behavior is not deterministic. Occasionally all tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I personally prefer, is having a clean database for each test using fixture. In this way, you would need refactoring to the `write_loop()` coroutine method to have db session as dependency injection instead of defining AsyncEngine inside the method and passing it to `write_to_db` and then reaching to db async session.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

async def write_loop(session: AsyncSession):
  async_engine: AsyncEngine = get_async_engine()
  while True:
    data = await get_some_data()
    bg_task: Task = asyncio.create_task(write_to_db(session, data))
    ...
```

Now, in this way, you can pass the test db session that could be an in-memory sqlite db session:

```py
# client.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncEngine

from module import models

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///:memory:"
engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

async def create_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(models.Base.metadata.create_all)

async def drop_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(models.Base.metadata.drop_all)
```

```py
#conftest.py
import pytest_asyncio
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from . import client

@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with client.async_session() as session:
        await client.create_tables()
        yield session
        await client.drop_tables()
```

```py
# test_something.py
import pytest
from interruptingcow import timeout
from module import functions

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_something(db: AsyncSession):
    try:
        with timeout(10, exception=asyncio.CancelledError):
            await functions.write_loop(session=db)
            assert False
    except:
        assert True
```

---

Another refactoring point that might be beneficial is splitting the `write_loop()` into two new functions namely `run_once()` and `run_forever()` — `run_once()` is inside of an infinite loop called `run_forever()`. In this way, you could easily test the `run_once()` function without needing an extra package such as `interruptingcow` for an interruption via a timeout.

Comment: I've already coupled the async engine and async session, but there is still an error. The error comes only when using minimal logical cores (e.g. 1 or 2). Meanwhile, when using 32 logical cores, the error is gone. I can set the number of logical cores used via pytest-xdist.